# The following NED types could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface

Tags: omnet++, mixim

I want to run my project through Cmdenv. In the project's omnetpp.ini file I specialized ned-path as: ned-path = /omnetpp-4.6/samples/VDLM4net;/omnetpp-4.6/samples/MiXiM/src/base;/omnetpp-4.6/samples/MiXiM/src/modules
And when I'm trying to use Cmdenv there is an error:[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPSy1.png)
I'm using omnetpp-4.6 on Windows with standalone project referenced to MiXiM-2.3

Comment: Your question implies that when using TkEnv running the project works. Are you using the same command line arguments?

Comment: Yes, in Tkenv it's all right. You question helped me to look in console when I was runnig my project in eclipse. I solved my problem. At first, in .ini file I specified all possible ned paths than potentially can be used in project. In my case it is look like this: ned-path = .;../MiXiM/examples;../MiXiM/src/base;../MiXiM/src/inet_stub;../MiXiM/src/modules . After it, in command line I wrote: ./VDLM4net -u Cmdenv -l ../MiXiM/src/mixim
 So, additionally, I specified the MiXiM shared liabrary. All works fine now.

Comment: Glad you were able to answer this question. If you have the time, feel free to post your solution as an answer to your question. This will make it easier to find for other users who might have the same or a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. At first, in .ini file I specified all possible ned paths than potentially can be used in project. In my case it is look like this: ned-path = .;../MiXiM/examples;../MiXiM/src/base;../MiXiM/src/inet_stub‌​;../MiXiM/src/module‌​s . After it, in command line I wrote: ./VDLM4net -u Cmdenv -l ../MiXiM/src/mixim So, additionally, I specified the MiXiM shared liabrary. All works fine now.

Comment: why it is so hard to use Cmdenv?! I am working with Veins-5.2 and my project is split between the 'src' and 'simulations' folders. The command line first told me that the ini file is not accessible, so I added '-f' and ini directory path to solve it. But then it told me "/libsrc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Could you please help me with this issue? which paths should I add and where?